# Python: Avoiding downloading html when taken to "page doesn't exist" error

Tags: python, loops, python-requests, http-status-code-404

I am teaching myself webscraping and wanted to download a bunch of .pgn files (essentially text files), using `requests`. Filenames are in the form of dates but are not strictly chronological. I ran a loop over possible dates, but if an indexed date doesn't correspond to a file, I still end up downloading the `filename.pgn` as a text file with the html of the error page. Instead, what I want is for these dates to be skipped.

Here's an example:

If I run:

```
filename = 'games9jul18.pgn'
url = 'https://www.chesspublishing.com/p/9/jul18/'+filename
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
with open(filename, 'wb') as e:
    e.write(response.text)
```

with the appropriate authentication in `payload`, the correct file `games9jul18.pgn` is saved. But if I run:

```
filename = 'games9aug18.pgn'
url = 'https://www.chesspublishing.com/p/9/aug18/'+filename
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
with open(filename, 'wb') as e:
    e.write(response.text)
```

I still get a saved file `games9aug18.pgn`, but instead of being a 'real' pgn file, it's a text file of the html of the error page. Navigating to the error page on my browser, it has no error code but a big chunk of text *The page you've asked may have been removed, or perhaps never existed.*

Unfortunately, it's not possible to loop only over the filenames corresponding to actual files, due to the inconsistent date structure. How can I add a condition to not create `.pgn` files if the error page is reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the response status. "Page not found" is 404, so you could check for that code or even check for a successful request, which is 200:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
if response.status == 200:
    with...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the code for successful request :200 when page is not found: 404.

```
if response.status_code ==200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as e:
        e.write(response.text)
```